# How to make clamassassin prepend the X-Virus-* headers instead of appending them?

Tags: clamav, procmail, smtp-headers

The email virus filter wrapper for ClamAV, `clamassassin`, appends its headers to the message headers.

```
X-Virus-Status: No
X-Virus-Checker-Version: clamassassin 1.2.4 with clamscan / ClamAV 1.0.3/27134/Mon Dec 25 11:40:06 2023
```

It would be better that any MTA delivering the message only *prepends* to the headers, as [RFC 5322, 3.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322.html#section-3.6) suggests:

> However, for the purposes of this specification, header fields SHOULD NOT be reordered when a message is transported or transformed.  More importantly, the trace header fields and resent header fields MUST NOT be reordered, and SHOULD be kept in blocks prepended to the message.  See sections [3.6.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322.html#section-3.6.6) and [3.6.7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322.html#section-3.6.7) for more information.

For instance, `spamassassin` prepends its `X-Spam-*` headers above the existing headers. Why `clamassassin` does not do the same, and how to alter this behaviour? If, e.g., the `.procmailrc` had the following I would expect these headers to appear in the same place.

```
:0 fw
| clamassassin

:0 fw
| spamassassin
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Reasons

The `clamassassin` is an old shell script that was developed between 2003 and 2007 whereas [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322.html) is more recent, dating back to 2008. Therefore, the author of `clamassassin`, James Lick, might not have been aware of such demands.

Furthermore, `clamassassin` utilizes Procmail's [`formail(1)`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/noble/man1/formail.1.html) *mail (re)formatter* for adding the headers. As `formail` only has `-a`, `-A`, `-i` & `-I` that all appends to the headers it is impossible to alter this behaviour without a major rewrite of the script.

### Workaround

As a workaround, I wrote a small script, [`mail-prepender.sh`](https://github.com/oh2fih/Misc-Scripts/blob/main/bin/mail-prepender.sh), that can be used to replace `formail` for the use case of `clamassassin`. It simply prepends all the headers given as any of those flags and keeps everything else intact. The flags `-x` & `-X` are also implemented as `clamassassin` uses `-c -x` for extracting the `Subject` header from the original headers.

On Debian based systems, the script is configurable through `/etc/default/clamassassin` where you can add the path to this script as the *path to `formail`* by adding, e.g.,

```
FORMAIL=/usr/local/bin/mail-prepender.sh
```

##### Results

Tested on Debian 12, where the beginning of the headers now look like this on clean results:

```
Return-Path: <sender@example.com>
X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 4.0.0 (2022-12-13) on mail.example.net
X-Spam-Status: No, score=-10.5 required=5.0 tests=BAYES_00,DKIMWL_WL_MED,
        DKIM_SIGNED,DKIM_VALID,DKIM_VALID_AU,SPF_PASS,USER_IN_DEF_DKIM_WL
        autolearn=ham autolearn_force=no version=4.0.0
X-Virus-Status: No
X-Virus-Checker-Version: clamassassin 1.2.4 with clamscan / ClamAV 1.0.3/27134/Mon Dec 25 11:40:06 2023
```

When ClamAV detects something the headers look like this:

```
Return-Path: <sender@example.com>
X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 4.0.0 (2022-12-13) on mail.example.net
X-Spam-Status: No, score=-2.1 required=5.0 tests=BAYES_00,DKIM_SIGNED,
        DKIM_VALID,DKIM_VALID_AU,DKIM_VALID_EF,SPF_PASS autolearn=ham
        autolearn_force=no version=4.0.0
X-Virus-Status: Yes
X-Virus-Report: Win.Test.EICAR_HDB-1 FOUND
X-Virus-Checker-Version: clamassassin 1.2.4 with clamscan / ClamAV 1.0.3/27132/Sat Dec 23 11:40:46 2023
```